# Missing dependencies while creating Anaconda environment

Tags: anaconda, graphlab

I tried to install GraphLab Create, so I created a new Anaconda environment, but it shows missing dependencies. I have no idea on how to remove it.

Terminal:

```
C:\Users\PC>conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0
```

The following error is raised:

```
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: .
Error:  Dependencies missing in current win-64 channels:
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_2 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda blas * mkl
```

I tried to type, this but the following happens

```
[Anaconda2] C:\Users\PC>anaconda search -t conda blas * mkl
usage: anaconda-script.py [-h] [--show-traceback] [--hide-traceback] [-v] [-q]
                          [--color] [--no-color] [-V] [-t TOKEN] [-s SITE]
                          ...
anaconda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: * mkl
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run command "conda update conda" , this will update the package manager then run your command again. I was facing the same issue and this solved it for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer and I ask revision of the strange answer by the author.